# (R): Turn a data.table line into a vector

Tags: r

Good evening!

I am a beginner in R, and I looked over stack overflow for similar questions, but could not find an answer. So sorry if I missed a similar post.

I have a really simple question:

[Datatable]

I have the above datatable, and I am just trying to draw a histogram of the values in the first line, for example (neglecting the first two columns).

But when I do try and type hist(data[1,][3:24]), Rstudio returns that "x must be numeric".

So is there a simple way I can turn this datatable line into a vector please? :)

And if so, what if I now want to draw a histogram of the whole data, not just the first row. Is there a way to append all the rows into one single vector (without using a for loop?).

Sorry if the question has already been asked,

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Use `unlist` to convert to a vector `hist(unlist(data[1,3:24]))` if it is a `data.table` or `tibble`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` or `tibble` won't coerce to `vector` by default when we select a single row.  One option is to use `unlist` to convert to `vector`

```
hist(unlist(data[1,3:24]))
```